# JavsScript works on browser console, but not when i put in developers console

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying create a responsive iframe (visualforce page). When I write this in the browser console it works:

```
document.querySelector('.oneAlohaPage>iframe').height = '300px'
```

However when I put it in the developers console, I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of null

I have tried to put it inside a `$(document).ready()` and `window.onload` and it still does not work. I also tried `window.setTimeout()` too.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused to what you're referring to as the 'browser console' and 'developer console'? `document.ready` and `window.load` are irrelevant if using the dev console to run some script, as the page *must* already have loaded for those to be available to use.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready() and window.onload you have already tried out, and also window.setTimeout(). Ideally one of this should have solved the issue. But seems it is not resolving in your case. Does the iframe has an 'id' ? You can try with 'id' selector inside setTimeout(). Sometimes parsing through the DOM and using >, + operators results in null object if dynamically rendered.

Wanted to post this as comment but unable to.

Comment: yes, it is rendered dynamically ... it has an id, but when I try to select it, the return is also null